# Write a DM to every user in a role

Tags: discord, discord.js

How can I write a DM to every user in a role? I'm going to make it so when you get a VoiceChannel joint that all are written in a certain role by DM. What's the best way to do that?

Heres my Code:

````
  const guild = bot.guilds.cache.get('601109434197868574');
  const voiceChannel = guild.channels.cache.get('706243822564409444');

  
  voiceChannel.members.forEach(member => {
    let sup = guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === '▬▬ Anastic | Supporter ▬▬⠀');
    sup.send('Hey!')

  })
}, 10000)```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sup` is a role and you are trying to send a message to the role itself, which is not possible. (`Role.send('Hey!'`).

You need to loop through the role members.

```js
const Guild = client.guilds.cache.get("GuildID");
if (!Guild) return false;

const Role = Guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == "▬▬ Anastic | Supporter ▬▬");
if (!Role) return false;

Role.members.forEach(member => {
    member.send("Hello!").catch(e => console.error(`Couldn't send the message to ${member.user.tag}!`));
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Thank you. I have a question, though. How can I make it that the bot sends only once a message?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your question.

Comment: If a user joins the VoiceChannel, the Bot sends the mesage every second. But I want that the bot is sending one message.

Comment: Could you also share the code above you showcase. You seem to be using setInterval.